# Displaying HTML contents over an applet - wmode transparent?

Tags: java, javascript, html, dhtml, z-index

For Flash content, I can set `wmode="transparent"` and display HTML menus over my Flash animation. Is something similar possible for Java applets, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773172/how-can-i-set-a-java-applet-transparency-to-show-contents-behind-it) and [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t125637-can-an-applet-be-transparent-or-given-z-index.html), it's not possible... Maybe someone else has a way, but as far as I know, there isn't any way to accomplish this...

Comment: Just to clarify - I want to display contents over the applet (for example, a DHTML menu with clickable links), not under it. But so far no luck...

Comment: Yeah... however as far as I know, just like flash, if the applet isn't transparent it effectively is on the topmost layer, "immune" to z-index. Like I said, maybe there is a way, if so you've asked on the right site!

Comment: By default, both flash and applets run in a window, not a layer, and are thus (equal to select dropdowns) not applicable to changes in z-index. Flash player behaviour can be configured, no idea about an applet.